# Tableau Crosstab Row Percentage of Whole

Tags: tableau-api, crosstab

I am new to Tableau and I have created a crosstab that shows a count of items per type. I want to add a column to my table. I need to know the percentage of the whole - I looked up a couple of things but I can't seem to find this exact problem.

```
Type       |Count      |% of Whole
-----------------------------------
A          |10         |1%
B          |99         |9.9%
C          |256        |25.6%
D          |300        |30%
E          |335        |33.5%
```

After reading some I think my issue is that I am not sure how to derive a calculation that is going to give a TOTAL # of Types. In Excel I would take the row value divided by the sum of all rows. Additionally I am fairly certain that this will lead to an issue once I filter this table - not sure I know how to preserve the percentages with filters.

I am using Tableau 9.2. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following calculated field:

```
SUM([Count])/TOTAL(SUM([Count]))
```

`TOTAL` takes into consideration all values of your variable.

Alternatively, you can use quick table calculation by right-clicking on count (here I'm using an example from the Superstore dataset):

[image]

Comment: Quick table calculation switches my Number of Record, Count in my example, to % of Total however I then lose the counts. I need both the counts and the percentages. I tried create a calculation because I get the same value. It seems that there isn't a way to format the display of a single column, unless I am missing something.

Comment: You lost me. If you want both `count` and `percentage of total` then leave `count` as it is and create new calculated field for `percentage of total`. Am I missing something? If you use quick table calculation then after changing your `count` to `Percent of total` just drag `count` again to your worksheet.